# Ich mag keine solchen Leute wie du/dich

Tags: colloquial

Welche Variante ist richtig?

> Ich will einfach mit keinen solchen Leuten kommunizieren wie **du/dir**.

> Ich mag keine solchen Leute wie **du/dich**.

Comment: Weißt Du, was in einfacheren Sätzen stehen würde, "Ich mag du/dich." bzw. "Ich will mit du/dir kommuniziern."?

Comment: Im 1. Satz wäre "wie mit dir" oder "wie du es bist" korrekt. Im 2. Satz ist "dich" korrekt.

Answer (score 1):

Im 1. Satz wäre "wie mit dir" oder "wie du es bist" korrekt.

Im 2. Satz ist "dich" korrekt.

Answer (score -1):

> 1. Ich will einfach mit keinen solchen Leuten kommunizieren wie **dir.**
> 2. Ich will einfach mit keinen solchen Leuten kommunizieren wie **mit dir.**

Die Version 2 ist die eigentlich korrekte Version. Die Version 1 ist auch nicht ganz falsch, es ist eine Ellipse, bei der das Wort *»mit«* weggelassen wurde, weil es davor bereits in derselben Funktion verwendet wurde.

Das Verb *»kommunizieren«* benötigt (wie jedes Verb) ein Subjekt. Das Subjekt von *kommunizieren* gibt an, wer der aktive Teilnehmer der Kommunikation ist. (Damit ist meist der Sender der Nachrichten gemeint.)

Der passive Teilnehmer der Kommunikation (also der Empfänger der Nachrichten) muss auch irgendwo im Satz stehen, und das Verb *kommunizieren* verlangt, dass dieser Kommunikationspartner in einem Präpositionalobjekt steht, und die Präposition, mit der dieses Präpositionalobjekt beginnt, muss da Wort *»mit«* sein.

Die Präposition *»mit«* verlangt aber, dass ihr inneres Objekt im Dativ steht. Der Nominativ wäre falsch.

> *richtig (Dat):* Ich kommuniziere mit **dir.**
> *falsch (Nom):* Ich kommuniziere mit **du.**

Daher auch:

> *richtig (Dat):* Ich kommuniziere mit **Leuten** wie **dir.**
> *falsch (Nom):* Ich kommuniziere mit **Leute** wie **du.**

---

> Ich mag keine solchen Leute wie **dich.**

Das Verb *»mag«* ist eine Form von *»mögen«.* Auch dieses Verb benötigt ein Subjekt. Das Subjekt von *mögen* gibt an, wer die Person ist, die das Gefühl hat.

Zusätzlich benötigt das Verb *mögen* ein Objekt, das angibt, auf wen sich dieses Gefühl bezieht. Das Verb *mögen* verlangt dieses Objekt im Akkusativ. Es muss also ein Akkusativobjekt sein. Der Nominativ wäre falsch.

> *richtig (Akk):* Ich mag **dich.**
> *falsch (Nom):* Ich mag **du.**

daher auch:

> *richtig (Akk):* Ich mag **Leute** wie **dich.**
> *falsch (Nom):* Ich mag **Leute** wie **du.**

(Hier erkennt man beim Substantiv *Leute* keinen Unterschied, weil Nominativ und Akkusativ von *»Leute«* gleich sind. Das ist im Plural bei allen deutschen Substantiven so.)

Comment: Ich halte “ich will einfach mit keinen solchen Leuten wie dir kommunizieren” für richtig und daher auch (1). Bei (2) bin ich versucht, eine ungewollte Bedeutung hineinzulesen.

Comment: Die Varianten mit „wie du“ können je nach Kontext ebenfalls korrekt sein, insbesondere wenn sie gesprochen werden und man das fehlende Komma nicht hört: *„Ich kommuniziere mit Leuten(, so) wie du (es tust).“* Oder: *„Ich mag Leute(, so) wie du (sie magst).“* Dieser Aspekt fehlt mir hier völlig; dafür ist der Rest wieder sehr ausschweifend.

Answer (score -5):

Bitte beide Varianten sind unzutreffend sie haben eine falsche Syntax.

Das ist eine `wortgenaue` Übersetzung aus dem Englischen. Und kein Deutscher selbst im Dialekt würde so reden. Deshalb kann es keine korrekte Form geben.

Bitte entschuldigt, aber wie weit kann man so etwas treiben? Ich glaube wir Anglizisieren.

Passiv/Aktiv und Plural/Singular sind nicht stimmig

"...keine solchen Leute..." wahrscheinlich "...no such people..."

"...wie dich" wahrscheinlich "...like you"

Gute Beispiele:

`Mit Leuten wie du rede ich nicht.`
Es behält die kurze imperative Intention.

`Ich hasse dich.` oder `Ich kann dich nicht leiden.`

*Erinnert Alles sehr an das Korrigieren von Englisch-Arbeiten.*

@planetmaker: Beispiele, nicht immer glücklich gewählt. Nicht korrekt aber besser und in Süddeutschland ugs. Anglizisieren nicht Anglizismen. Ich schimpfe nicht, das ist nicht angebracht und ein  Vorurteil, das ist persönlich.

@jonathan-scholbach: Wer Sprache lernt braucht erstmal klare einfache Konstrukte, damit er sie versteht und nachvollziehen kann. Dieser Satz ist WORTGENAU übersetzt. Bitte lesen sie den meinen Text nochmal, es steht alles darin. Der Fragende will verstehen und nicht akademisiert werden. Wir sind alle in Gefahr. Ich wollte hier, auf dieser Plattform, eine andere Sprache lernen und bin weg, weil es zuviel an Falsch-Richtigem gab. Anonsten ist die Antwort von @hubert-schölnast sehr gut.

NACHTRAG: Anglizisieren meint etwaige Konstruktion aus dem Englischen entnehmen und im Deutschen verwenden.

Comment: Kannst du bitte genauer ausführen, was du für falsch hältst und wie es richtig heißen müsste?

Comment: Verstehe ich das richtig, Du hältst "Mit Leuten wie du rede ich nicht" für korrektes Deutsch? Falls ich es missverstanden habe, schlage ich vor, mehr des Textes auf die eigentliche Antwort zu verwenden denn auf das Schimpfen auf Anglizismen.

Comment: Hi romanvolak! Willkommen hier bei German.SE! Erstmal: Danke für deine Antwort! Sie enthält einen großen Anteil allgemeiner Erwägungen, die für die Frage zumindest irrelevant und vielleicht auch gar nicht zutreffend sind. Bei Jemandem, der Deutsch lernt und bereits Englisch spricht wäre es nicht allzu verwunderlich, wenn da Anglizismen auftauchen. Ich weiß nicht, ob das hier der Fall ist, aber es könnte doch sein. Deine Antwort wäre hilfreicher, wenn Sie stärker _erklärt_ und weniger _bewertet_, und wenn sie stärker auf die _Spezifika_ der Frage eingeht statt _allgemeine_ Aussagen trifft.